# Layout messes up when zoomed out

Tags: html, css, fixed-width

I've made a fixed layout and it works great on all browsers. But when zoomed out at least one wheel scroll (90%) the second navigation (#header-navigation) items break into more lines and that pushes elements below out of their places. I tried setting font-size, padding and margin using em and %, but no good. If I make overflow: hidden for #header-navigation, I can zoom out up to 50% with no problems. That's totally enough for me, but hiding is not an option, however.

You can see it here: http://palivonas.lt/test/stackoverflow/

EDIT: Got it working on Chrome and IE9 (thanks @GGG), but Firefox still pushes #social box down, even though line doesn't break in navigation any more.

Comment: It's a clearing issue, why don't you use a grid system that takes care of this for you? 978.gs / twitter bootstrap

Comment: I wanted to, but the designer (I only did html/css part) made it really incompatible with 960.gs and 978.gs...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix.

Change the list items' `display` property to `inline-block`, and remove `float`.

```css
#header-navigation li {

    background: url(images/slash_header.png) right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 26px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the ordered list containing the navigation.

```css
ol, ul {

    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out when I'm home.

Comment: It fixed layout on Chrome, but Firefox still pushes the "follow us" box down. Surprisingly, on IE9 everything works right even without the fix. But IE7 doesn't understand inline-block.

Comment: @AndriusPalivonas crap, I forgot about IE. I think it can do `inline-block`, but only on elements that were `inline` to begin with. I don't know how much the exact font matters to you, but you could simply replace `Tahoma, Verdana` with `Helvetica` and fix everything. Tahoma and Verdana have really wide characters.

Comment: IE7 wouldn't be a huge loss (I fixed it anyways, but Firefox is. I can't change fonts, it's a requirement from the client...